Average of two strings in alphabetical/lexicographical order with `PAD SPACE` Rules
This is a followup of questions/2510755
What's the best way to find the average of 2 strings with an added constraint that trailing space does not matter to the comparison (the way databases do a PAD SPACE comparison)?
The answer in questions/2510755 works great but can lead to trailing space at the end. I am trying to find average of strings with a constraint that trialing space does not matter to the comparison.
This essentially means that the zeroth position has a radix of one less than the rest and may be I could use a concept of mix radix (like hours and minutes) to find average but I am not entirely sure if that's the right thing to do.

Combined use of trimming the trailing spaces and then calculating the average of the trimmed strings can solve your problem.
Trailing spaces have to be trimmed: Remove the trailing spaces from the strings present.
Then we have to calculate average: Find the midpoint character by character between the 2 trimmed strings.
sample code-
def average(str1, str2):

    trim_str1 = str1.rstrip()
    trim_str2 = str2.rstrip()


    max_len = max(len(trim_str1), len(trim_str2))
    trim_str1 = trim_str1.ljust(max_len)
    trim_str2 = trim_str2.ljust(max_len)
    

    avg_str = ''
    for ch1, ch2 in zip(trim_str1, trim_str2):
        avg_ch = chr((ord(ch1) + ord(ch2)) // 2)
        avg_str += avg_ch

    return avg_str.rstrip()

str1 = "Sample   "
str2 = "Function"
average_str = average(str1, str2)
print(f"Average of the strings is: '{average_str}'")


Thanks.
My problem is that avg_ch can produce a trailing space and I am not sure if stripping that might be the right midpoint. Your answer will definitely work in most practical situations, as ascii(or unicode) value of space is before all characters (irrespective of the characterset/collation ) I hope so.
